# YAML pipeline resource trigger not working

Tags: azure-devops

I have been trying to get a YAML pipeline resource trigger to work. I realise that similar questions have been asked in the past but I have not been able to find a solution based on these.

The situation is as follows:

- `tests-pipeline` runs on a nightly schedule (defined in the YAML) and runs some extended regression tests
- `release-pipeline` is supposed to be triggered by a successful run of `tests-pipeline`. This pushes the latest build packages to various repositories.

`tests-pipeline` runs fine.

`release-pipeline` is not being triggered. I can run it fine manually. It has the following:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  name: MyBuildPool
  demands:
  - Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT
  - Agent.ComputerName -equals <specific machine for release pipelines>

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: tests_pipeline # Arbitrary name used in this pipeline
    source: tests-pipeline    # Name of pipeline as defined in ADO
    trigger: true            # run this pipeline when test-pipeline completes
```

- Both pipelines are defined in the same repository and the same project.
- Both are meant to run on our "main" development branch (the one that we merge feature branches to).
- The "default branch for manual and scheduled builds" is set to be the "main" branch in the ADO UI for the release pipeline (this is one of the pieces of advice that crops up in other questions).
- The test pipeline publishes an artifact, even though strictly it does not need to, as this was another thing (lack of artifact) that has been noted as preventing these triggers from working.

I have tried various renaming of my test pipeline. My understanding is that the name in the YAML pipeline resources `source` parameter should match the name of the pipeline as it is assigned in the ADO UI. However, I have tried various things like shortening it, removing spaces that were originally in it, changing the pipeline name to match the YAML file name, etc.

The really frustrating thing here is that I have a pair of small experimental pipelines in the same project and repo that are meant to model the test and release pipeline, and I can get these to trigger. When I got these working, I thought I knew how to do this, but when I have applied to the real pipelines, it doesn't work!

I am looking for ideas about things I might have missed or how I might go about debugging this.

**Edit**

Couple of extra things tried recently:

- I mentioned above that I have a pair of toy pipelines working as required. I tried swapping the upstream `source` of the "real" release pipeline from the "real" tests pipeline to the toy tests pipeline and this worked. This is frustratingly close. What could it be about the real upstream pipeline that prevents the trigger from working. The real tests pipeline has a schedule trigger defined in the YAML and that is one thing I have not tried to reproduce in my toy pipelines. Could that be it?
- I have been able to set up the required trigger in the ADO UI by going to the "Triggers" menu while editing the pipeline and setting a "Build completion" trigger there. This will be my fallback option, but I would prefer to do it all in the YAML if possible.

Comment: What is name in ui for tests-pipeline? Is it shown exactly "tests-pipeline"? UI name can be different from yaml filename, that might be the reason

Comment: Yes it is the exact UI name of the pipeline. I have tried renaming it in the UI (and changing it to match in the pipeline YAML) in case something like spaces in the name was an issue. However, nothing I have tried has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question in case it proves useful for someone else.

I don't know if the following is the only way this can be resolved or if it is expected behaviour or documented in any way, but it has now worked for me in two different cases. Apologies if it seems a bit "cargo cult".

For clarity, let's assume we have the following pipelines:

- `"My Tests Pipeline"` - this is the name of the pipeline in ADO UI. This is defined by a YAML file `tests-pipeline.yml` say.
- `"My Release Pipeline"` defined by a YAML file `release-pipeline.yml`.

If we want to trigger `"My Release Pipeline"` to run when "My Tests Pipeline" has run successfully, the `release-pipeline.yml` file has to contain a section like this:

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: tests_pipeline   # Arbitrary name used in this pipeline
    source: My Tests Pipeline  # Name of pipeline as defined in ADO
    trigger: true              # Run this pipeline when tests pipeline completes
```

This is essentially what I had and it was not working. However, the key to it seems to be that if the pipeline `"My Tests Pipeline"` already existed in ADO, and the release pipeline YAML is edited to *add* the pipeline trigger, the trigger doesn't work. Similarly, if the triggering `source` is edited to point to a *different* pipeline, it stops working.

The resolution was, for me, to **delete** `"My Tests Pipeline"` in ADO and **recreate** it.

Note that this is a lightweight operation as the recreated pipeline is based on exactly the same YAML definition as the one just deleted. The recreated pipeline can be given exactly the same name as the deleted one.

To be clear, the YAML content was fine and did not need adjusting. As far as I can tell there are no significant restrictions on the `source` pipeline name - the name just needs to match the name of the pipeline as assigned in the ADO UI. This is what I have done all along.

Each time, after recreating the downstream pipeline in ADO, I have run that pipeline manually before testing the triggering from the upstream pipeline. I don't know if this would make any difference, but I mention it because I have not yet tested a pipeline trigger without doing that manual run first, and it is possible that this step is significant.